# DatePicker dialog and button => click twice to open

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

i create a dialog in my `onCreate` method in my normal activity:

```
 datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, cal.get(YEAR),
                    cal.get(MONTH), cal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

then i call a button listener :

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datePicker.show();
                Log.e("tag", "Passage dans le click");

            }
        });
```

when cancel =>

1. when i click this button one time, the datepicker showing.
2. i click cancel on the dialog
3. i click on the button second time, the datepicker showing

when OK =>

1. when i click this button one time, the datepicker showing.
2. i click OK on the dialog
3. i click on the button second time, the datepicker NOT showing

howewer if i write twice `Datepicker.show()`, that work  :

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    datePicker.show();
                     datePicker.show();
                    Log.e("tag", "Passage dans le click");

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below code... A dialog object is every time create and it would be showing every time. hope it will work.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

       datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, cal.get(YEAR), cal.get(MONTH), cal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH));

                datePicker.show();
                Log.e("tag", "Passage dans le click");

            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that work great, howewer i declare twice  datePicker = new DatePickerDialog (...), in the oncreate ( i need it to show the dialog at the creation ) and in the listener.

Comment: Yes for that you can create multiple dialog and its object and multiple listener, so you can handle it easily, it would be appreciated if you vote up too for the answer.

Comment: i'am new here i can't vote up for you, i need 15 reputations, sorry :) 
but i "check" your answer

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to some kind of "heavy" work on onDateSet(...) callback.
Try to use this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    datePicker.show();

                }
            }, 300);
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, thank you, but that doesn't work, when i click ok on the Datepicker Dialog it's like the program was waiting something.